# What "private property" means on ES6 classes?

Tags: javascript, oop, private

I am a bit lost with ES6 privacy on Classes. I have this Class:

```
class Whatever {

        constructor(value) {
            this._value = Number(value);
        }

        total() {
            return this._value * 2;
        }
    }

    let instance = new Whatever('1000');
    console.log(instance.total() );     // 2000     
    console.log(instance._value  );     // 1000
```

I am trying to learn how Symbol() works to keep data private ([see link](http://2ality.com/2016/01/private-data-classes.html#using-symbols-as-keys-for-private-properties)), and after reading the documentation I am trying to make a simple example about it, but does not seem to have any difference:

```
const _value = Symbol('value');

    class Whatever {

        constructor(value) {
            this[_value] = Number(value);
        }

        total() {
            return this[_value] * 2;
        }
    }


    let instance = new Whatever('1000');
    console.log(instance.total() );     // 2000     
    console.log(instance[_value]  );    // 1000
```

Could someone explain me on a comprehensive way, what does privacy mean on this case, and why my idea of privatizing data (making data unaccesible from outside the Class) is wrong? I have not much experience on OOP.

Thank you.

Comment: It's just the same, and as the linked article mentions: they (both) "*are somewhat hidden from the outside world, but not completely*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No real difference in your example, assuming you don't loop through the enumerable properties of the class.

Consider the following:

```
function MyFunction () {
  const _private = new Symbol();

  this[_private] = 5;
  this.public = 10;
}

const thing = new MyFunction();

for (let key in thing) { // prints 10
  console.log(thing[key]);
}

console.log(thing.public); // prints 10
console.log(thing._private); // undefined
```

Properties named by symbols are not enumerable, so in a sense they're not "exposed". Another benefit of symbols is that they're guaranteed to create unique keys, so there's no worry of key name collisions.

I chose to illustrate it with a function rather than a class for simplicity sake. For a class you could do the following (it's all about scope for "protecting" the symbol):

```
const MyClass = (function () {
  const _value = Symbol();
  return class _MyClass {
    constructor() {
      this[_value] = 5;
    }
  }
})();
```

Disclaimer: It's not "true" privacy, since there are still ways to enumerate the symbols. I think the biggest advantage is for the name collisions.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few subtle concepts at play here.

`Symbol`s are globally unique; that is, if you call `Symbol.create('somestring');` twice, it will produce two completely different symbols.

There is no way for "someone else" to access an object property whose key is a symbol** without access to that symbol in some other way. In your second example, code underneath the class still has lexical access to the symbol. However, this would not be the case were your class to be exported, whether through a module system or just returned to some other calling function without lexical access, even if they knew what string you used to label the symbol, because they can't re-create it (as mentioned above).

** edit 2: As others stated, including Dr. Rauschmayer, "others" can access the keys, including symbols, via `Reflect.ownKeys(object)`. In this very deliberate case, one would hope that the other party knows what they're doing... so this whole paradigm of using symbols as keys is still good for ensuring non-clashing namespaces for keys (e.g., if someone else wanted to augment your object without accidentally overriding any of its important "internal" properties). However, it is not sufficient for 100% protection against deliberate access or modification. (There's a related [ECMAScript proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-fields) in the works, interesting read.)

Edit: here's an example

```js
let Whatever = (function() {
      const _value = Symbol('value');

      class Whatever {

        constructor(value) {
          this[_value] = Number(value);
        }

        total() {
          return this[_value] * 2;
        }
      }
      
      return Whatever;
    })(); // IIFE


    let instance = new Whatever('1000');
    console.log(instance.total()); // 2000     
    console.log(instance._value); // undefined
    console.log(instance[_value]); // ReferenceError: _value is not defined
```

Comment: @le_m Ah, you're right. So that would be a case of deliberate reflection by the other party instead of just trying to prevent name clashes. Thank you for pointing out, I'll update my answer to note.

Comment: Very grateful, thank you. I've marked the other answer as both are valid but the oldest one is the other.